# How to generate a cartesian plane system with functions in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to do something like this using tikz. The problem for me is to represent fuctions. Someone could help me please

[image]

Comment: Please include a minimal example with the code for a small document showing where you are and what you've tried. This makes it much easier for people to help, much more likely they will and much less likely their efforts will be inapplicable. Do-it-for-me s are not really fair questions to ask, although that is not to say that people won't answer them as shouldn't. (Including me if I like the question.) If you want to post do-it-for-me s make sure you only ask for help with visually appealing stuff as those are the shouldn't-be-answered which often get answered. Donkeys at Christmas are ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Simple functions can be plotted using the `pgfplots` package and its `\addplot {f(x)};` See example below and [the manual for `pgfplots`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) page 53.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot {x^2};
        \addplot {sqrt(x)*10};
        \addplot {exp(x/2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution. Sometimes, depending on complexity, I just use the "plot" path option in tikz.